# Javascript - Check if div element exists by id

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

```js
const d = document.getElementById("added");
if (d) {
  d.innerHTML = "Test2";
} else {
  d = document.createElement("div");
  d.innerHTML = "Test3";
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
<div id="added_2">Test1</div>
```

I want to check if a `div` element exists. If yes, then change its `innerHTML` property, else create it with some other `innherHMTL`. I use the above code and it works if the `div` already exists but otherwise it gives the error `Javascript - Check if div element exists by id`...

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Comment: What is the error message? You cannot reassign `d`, since it’s declared with `const`. Either choose a different variable name or use `let` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You defined `d` as const, so you can't overwrite it. Use `let` instead and you should be OK:

```js
let d = document.getElementById("added");
if (d) {
  d.innerHTML = "Test2";
} else {
  d = document.createElement("div");
  d.innerHTML = "Test3";
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
<div id="added_2">Test1</div>
```